# Estrutura de repetição dentro da seleção no visualg

Tags: loop, visualg, syntax-error

Função :Escreva um programa que crie um vetor inicialmente zerado e insira um valor no vetor, numa posição informada. Por exemplo, para o vetor vazio v = { }, posição 4 e valor 10, o programa deve gerar v={ , , ,10}. Se a posição for 2 e o valor 5, o vetor ficara v = { , 5, ,10}. E assim, sucessivamente. Caso a posição esteja ocupada, os valores devem ser remanejados, de modo a deixar a posição escolhida, livre para a inserção do novo valor, o vetor ficara v = { , 23, 5, ,10}. Mostre o vetor após as inserções.

parada<-"s"
para cont de 1 ate 5 faca
   x[cont]<-0
fimpara
enquanto (parada="s") faca
   escreva("Digite uma posição até 4 que queira alterar: ")
   leia(posi)
   enquanto (posi>4) faca
      escreva("Digite uma posição até 4 que queira alterar: ")
      leia(posi)
   fimenquanto
   escreva("Digite o valor que deseja inserir nessa posição: ")
   leia(valor)
   posi2<-posi+1
   se (x[posi]=0)entao
      x[posi]<-valor
   senao
      para cont de 5 ate posi2 faca
         **cont2<-(cont-1)

         x[cont]<-x[cont2]

      fimpara**
      x[posi]<-valor
   fimse
   repita
      escreva("Deseja continuar?('S'/'N'): ")
      leia(parada)
   ate (parada="s") ou (parada="n")
fimenquanto
escreval("==============Resultado das alterações=================")
para cont de 1 ate 5 faca
   escreval(x[cont]," na posição ",cont)
fimpara

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

essa parte em negrito e a parte em vermelho na imagem o visualg não lê, ele pula direto pro "x[posi]<-valor" em baixo do fimpara e eu preciso dessa repetição pra alterar os valores da posição. Eu fiz dessa forma, alguem sabe se está incorreto ou se tem outra forma de fazer esse exercicio??

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEMA RESOLVIDO

para cont de 5 ate posi2 **passo-1** faca 
cont2<-(cont-1)
x[cont]<-x[cont2]
fimpara

era o comando **passo-1** que estava faltando, com ele a estrutura *para* consegue fazer a contagem em ordem regressiva.